# Powershell Invoke-SqlCmd: Incorrect syntax near 'C:'

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am running PowerShell to execute a stored procedure called `spImportReturn`.

Using the `Invoke-Sqlcmd` cmdlet, this works fine as follows:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "LONSQL01\SQLEXPRESS" -Database "ReturnsDatabase" -Query "EXEC spImportReturn @FileDirectory='C:\Users\User1\D3R\staging\returns\'"   -verbose 4> C:\Temp\DbAdmin\ImportD3RReturn\ImportD3rReturn.txt
```

However when I replace this as follows, it doesn't work:

```
$FileDirectory = "C:\Users\User1\D3R\staging\returns\"

Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "LONSQL01\SQLEXPRESS" -Database "ReturnsDatabase" -Query "EXEC spImportReturn @FileDirectory = $FileDirectory"   -verbose 4> C:\Temp\DbAdmin\ImportD3RReturn\ImportD3rReturn.txt
```

I get the following error:

> Invoke-Sqlcmd : Incorrect syntax near 'C:'.

I've properly enclosed `$FileDirectory` in quotes... so what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Use `'$FileDirectory'` - you still need to wrap it in quotes that SQL Server can see.

Comment: You are two extra spaces in second command.  One before the equal sign and one after the equal sign.

Comment: I don't even want to think about what `spImportReturn` does, or why it's doing file access. Why aren't you using `Invoke-SqlCmd` with your query directly to export it to a file in Powershell, or maybe `Invoke-DbaQuery` or `bcp.exe`